# Create an integer default field value containing epoch of now()

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have a MySQL table where I am recording token creation times and I would like to create the equivalent of this Postgres construct:

```
token_start_times INTEGER DEFAULT EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

MySQL provides unix_timestamp(now()) but it returns a timestamp value and not an integer value.

I tried this

```
token_start_times INTEGER DEFAULT timestamp(now())
```

but MySQL complains about the syntax.  I read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485803/create-field-with-default-as-epoch-time) but it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: A timestamp **is** an integer. But you can't put function calls into the `DEFAULT` option.

Comment: The function call was a hail mary pass.   I looked through the documentation and I didn't see any value I could isolate with Extract.  I may have to refactor and move the functionality into the code.

Comment: With all the power and flexibility behind `DATETIME` and `TIMESTAMP`, why do you want a plain `INT`?

Comment: It is far faster and simpler to perform calculations on integers when processing tokens.   In general, I store all my JWT token create and expire values as INT.

Answer (score 1):

try this to get the value as integer:

```
SELECT now()+0;
```

Comment: His question is about making this the default value of a column, not how to select it.

Answer (score 0):

It appears the only way to do what I want to do is with an AFTER INSERT trigger.  I prefer not to use triggers as it causes the development environment to increase in complexity.  For more details see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5331026/is-it-possible-to-create-a-column-with-a-unix-timestamp-default-in-mysql) by Ike Walker.